Molecule[ec2] Troubles
I've been using Ansible in a basic manner for sometime now and trying to get to grips with Molecule. I'm using the ec2 driver with my role and so far managed to create an ec2 instance in aws for molecule testing. Where its going wrong is when i try to do a molecule login. I end up with this error:
*Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/ansible/molecule_ec2/bin/molecule", line 8, in 
sys.exit(main())
File "/home/ansible/molecule_ec2/lib/python3.10/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1157, in call
return self.main(*args, **kwargs)
File "/home/ansible/molecule_ec2/lib/python3.10/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1078, in main
rv = self.invoke(ctx)
File "/home/ansible/molecule_ec2/lib/python3.10/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1688, in invoke
return _process_result(sub_ctx.command.invoke(sub_ctx))
File "/home/ansible/molecule_ec2/lib/python3.10/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1434, in invoke
return ctx.invoke(self.callback, **ctx.params)
File "/home/ansible/molecule_ec2/lib/python3.10/site-packages/click/core.py", line 783, in invoke
return __callback(*args, **kwargs)
File "/home/ansible/molecule_ec2/lib/python3.10/site-packages/click/decorators.py", line 33, in new_func
return f(get_current_context(), *args, **kwargs)
File "/home/ansible/molecule_ec2/lib/python3.10/site-packages/molecule/command/login.py", line 129, in login
base.execute_subcommand(scenario.config, subcommand)
File "/home/ansible/molecule_ec2/lib/python3.10/site-packages/molecule/command/base.py", line 157, in execute_subcommand
return command(config).execute(args)
File "/home/ansible/molecule_ec2/lib/python3.10/site-packages/molecule/logger.py", line 188, in wrapper
rt = func(*args, *kwargs)
File "/home/ansible/molecule_ec2/lib/python3.10/site-packages/molecule/command/login.py", line 56, in execute
self._get_login(hostname)
File "/home/ansible/molecule_ec2/lib/python3.10/site-packages/molecule/command/login.py", line 96, in _get_login
login_options = self._config.driver.login_options(hostname)
File "/
I'm a bit baffled here as the official molecule[ec2] driver documentation leaves much to be desired!
Here is my create.yml
---
- name: Create
  hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  gather_facts: true
  no_log: false
  vars:
    ami_id: "ami-0c1c30571d2dae5c9"
    key_pair_name: molecule_key
    key_pair_path: "~/.cache/molecule/{{ role_name }}/default"
    role_name: someorg.ftp
    security_group_name: molecule
    security_group_rules:
      - proto: tcp
        from_port: "{{ ssh_port }}"
        to_port: "{{ ssh_port }}"
        cidr_ip: '10.1.0.0/16'
      # - proto: tcp
      #   from_port: 5986 # for windows roles
      #   to_port: 5986
      #   cidr_ip: '10.1.0.0/16'
    ssh_port: 22
    ssh_user: ubuntu

  tasks:
    - name: Find the VPC for the subnet
      amazon.aws.ec2_vpc_subnet_info:
        subnet_ids: "{{ item.vpc_subnet_id }}"
      loop: "{{ molecule_yml.platforms }}"
      register: subnet_info

    - name: Create molecule EC2 security group
      amazon.aws.ec2_security_group:
        vpc_id: "{{ item.subnets[0].vpc_id }}"
        name: "{{ security_group_name }}"
        description: "Temporary security group for Molecule testing"
        rules: "{{ security_group_rules }}"
      loop: "{{ subnet_info.results }}"

    - name: Test for presence of local key pair
      ansible.builtin.stat:
        path: "{{ key_pair_path }}"
      register: key_pair_local

    - name: Create key pair
      amazon.aws.ec2_key:
        name: "{{ key_pair_name }}"
        key_type: "rsa"
        tags:
          Name: molecule-temporary-keypair
      no_log: false
      register: key_pair

    - name: Write the SSH key
      ansible.builtin.copy:
        content: >
          {{ key_pair.key.private_key }}
        dest: "{{ key_pair_path }}/{{ key_pair_name }}"
        mode: "0600"
      check_mode: false
      delegate_to: localhost
      no_log: false
      run_once: true

    - name: Create EC2 instance(s)
      amazon.aws.ec2_instance:
        instance_type: "{{ item.instance_type }}"
        image_id: "{{ item.image_id }}"
        key_name: "{{ key_pair_name }}"
        security_group: "{{ security_group_name }}"
        subnet_id: "{{ item.vpc_subnet_id }}"
        tags:
          Name: molecule-tmp-instance
        wait: true
        wait_timeout: 300
      register: server
      loop: "{{ molecule_yml.platforms }}"

    # Mandatory configuration for Molecule to function.

    - name: Populate instance config dict
      ansible.builtin.set_fact:
        instance_conf_dict: {
          'instance': "{{ item.instances[0].tags.Name }}",
          'address': "{{ item.instances[0].private_ip_address }}",
          'user': "{{ ssh_user }}",
          'port': "{{ ssh_port }}",
          'identity_file': "{{ key_pair_path }}/{{ key_pair_name }}",
          'instance_ids': "{{ item.instance_ids }}"
        }
      with_items: "{{ server.results }}"
      register: instance_config_dict
      when: server.changed | bool

    - name: Convert instance config dict to a list
      ansible.builtin.set_fact:
        instance_conf: "{{ instance_config_dict.results | map(attribute='ansible_facts.instance_conf_dict') | list }}"
      when: server.changed | bool

    - name: Dump instance config
      ansible.builtin.copy:
        content: "{{ instance_conf | to_nice_yaml }}"
        dest: "{{ molecule_instance_config }}"
        mode: "0600"
      when: server.changed | bool

    - name: Wait for SSH
      ansible.builtin.wait_for:
        port: "{{ ssh_port }}"
        host: "{{ item.address }}"
        search_regex: SSH
        delay: 10
        timeout: 320
      with_items: "{{ lookup('file', molecule_instance_config) | from_yaml }}"

Here is my molecule.yml
---
dependency:
  name: galaxy
driver:
  name: ec2
  ssh_connection_options:
    -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null
    -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no
    -i ~/.cache/molecule/tmk.crushftp/default/molecule_key
platforms:
  - name: instance
    image_owner: "099720109477"
    image_id: ami-0c1c30571d2dae5c9
    region: eu-west-1
    key_inject_method: cloud-init
    instance_type: t2.micro
    ssh_user: ubuntu
    vpc_subnet_id: subnet-1234567xxxxxxxxxx
    instance_tags:
      - Name: molecule-tmp-instance
provisioner:
  name: ansible
  env:
    ANSIBLE_HOST_KEY_CHECKING: false
  playbooks:
    create: create.yml
    destroy: destroy.yml
  lint:
    name: ansible-lint
verifier:
  name: testinfra
scenario:
  name: default

Also just an fyi using the private key generated here I can manually connect to the instance fine. Its just when i use molecule login it fails :(
Has anybody got this working successfully? Any boilerplate, tips or pointers would be appreciated greatly!
Tried to follow the examples here:
https://github.com/ansible-community/molecule-ec2
And ended up where I am now.
